# Does this question belong on SO?

Tags: support, specific-question, scope, site-recommendation

Does this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485173/understanding-sldnf-forest-of-goal-%e2%86%90foundingx belong on SO?

I am taking a course in logic programming, this question is from the book I am using.

I am not sure where to ask it.

I did not find any tag with SLD nor SLDNF here.

For users who cannot see deleted questions:

> I am trying to understand this program and the respective forest.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Question:
>
> - In the main tree, why from ←off_gound(a) can you derive ⧠ ?
> - In the main tree, why was chosed on(b,a) first instead of on(c,b)?
>
> Could someone please explain this?

Comment: *Maybe* on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), but read about [on-topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there first, and transcribe the question so it's not two pictures from a textbook.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Btw, How would I transcribe the tree diagram? I know a little bit of latex, but not that much like to plot the tree.

Comment: I don't know how okay Computer Science is with pictures. You could create an ASCII diagram with something like [asciiflow](http://asciiflow.com/) and post it in code tags.

Comment: @BenjaminW. A photo of the tree from the book is likely far more readable than some ASCII art, though...

Comment: I don't think the image of the tree will be the problem. But the text should definitely be transcribed.

Comment: @Lw. K has asked the question on CS.SE: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/97741/understanding-sldnf-forest

Comment: Trees are probably not Google-search-able anyway, so it is not very useful to convert it to ASCII-art.

Comment: Could be a valid Prolog program. Of course book photos are not ok.

Comment: @Bergi:  It definitely reads like valid Prolog to me, but I'm not sure if that's the crux of the question.